# VB: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)

Tags: excel, vb.net, office-interop

I am working on an app which needs to import data from Excel.

My solution is using `Microsoft.office.Interop.Excel.`

But I get this error when I debug:

> Message=Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the
>   following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

Below is my code:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.office.Interop.Excel

Private Sub BExcel1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BExcel1.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx; *.xls; *.xlsm"
    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        ExcelPath1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If

    Dim XlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim XlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim XlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    XlWorkBook = XlApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelPath1.Text)

 End Sub
```

I have googled to find some solutions (as following), but they didn't work out:

1. I have repaired Office
2. I have repaired Visual Studio
3. I have used the registry editor to check the `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\`, but under the `00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046`, I got only one version 1.9, it seems not like the conflict between two version?

Any ideas to fix this problem?

```
VS version:2017 community

Excel version:2016

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version:15.0.0.0
```

Comment: Repairing office is not good enough, re-install it.  Run chkdsk.exe before you do so to verify that the disk drive is still in decent shape.

Comment: Excel 2016 should be showing version 16.#, not 15, which is Office 2013. Where are you seeing these conflicting version numbers?

Comment: @Cindy  the version of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel is from the Reference Properties of Visual Studio Property Manager. It shows 15.0.0.0. And the key 00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046 under the Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\, it got only sub key 1.9 (Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\TypeLib\{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\1.9) ,under the Default tag : Data: Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library). I have not seen any conflicting version numbers, so I am confuse.

Comment: Which version of Excel is installed on your machine?

Comment: @Cindy Office 2016 standard.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the tip, I would try it later.

Comment: OK... How did you "Import" the Excel library (PIA) to your project? In the Properties/References did you Add from the .NET tab or the COM tab? The PIAs offered via the .NET tab are pre-installed by Visual Studio and may not correspond to the version of Office you have installed. Always use the COM tab and look for entries such as "Microsoft Excel ...." and "Microsoft Office..."

Comment: @CindyMeister OK, I see. I import PIA from the Assemblies\Extensions tab (I assume it would be .Net tab ?), not from the COM tab. I am searching the COM tab now, but couldn't find PIA refernce?

Comment: Do you see entries that begin with "Microsoft Excel" and "Microsoft Office", as I indicated in my last comment? Those are what you need to look for in the COM tab. There won't be anything about "PIA" - adding the reference to the COM libraries should automatically pick up the PIAs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try to run Visual Studio with the `/ResetUserData` command line argument. Read more about that in the [Error "Unable to cast COM object..." when exporting to Microsoft Excel from Team Explorer 2008](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/968263/error-unable-to-cast-com-object-when-exporting-to-microsoft-excel-from) article.

Obviously you are trying to connect to a wrong Excel version. Looks like you have some extra windows registry keys left after uninstalling an old version of Office or vice versa. Anyway, take a look at the [How to solve “Unable to cast COM object of type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass’ to interface type ‘Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application’”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dau-blog/2012/04/20/how-to-solve-unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-applicationclass-to-interface-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-_application/) blog post which describes exactly the same issue. Basically you need to find a wrong entry in the windows registry and then delete it.

BTW When you add a new COM reference to the project a missed PIA is generated automatically (if it doesn't exist any longer). So, that is a possible way to go. Also you may try to embed interop types into your own assembly like the following screenshot shows:

[image]

Comment: It would be good for downvoters to describe or just leave a comment why they think the post doesn't answer the question posted or addresses an issue.

Comment: I imagine the downvotes are because this is pretty much "link-only" content, to outside sources. The site guidelines specify that information should be *on-site*, not external to the site. And if it's already on-site a question should be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm down voting because the info was provided in a link which is now dead, which is why link-only responses are frustrating.

Comment: In this case the link to MS was spot on and the solution to my issue.  Thank you for providing it.  They both open for me.  Just for reference mine came from a service app written WPF/C# in VS2019.  This was a "new machine" that had junk from a an attempt to install an old version of Office that was incorrectly deleted and a new version installed.  The question and your solution helped GREATLY.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `Embed Interop Types` property to `True` (since .NET Framework 4.0)  and the `Specific Version` property to `False` for the Office Interop assembly reference, then your code should work with any version of Excel.

However, you must compile the code with the same bitness as your Office. For a 32-bit version of Office, you must compile your code as `x86`, otherwise this exception can still occur on a 64-bit machine!